# How to output two files using grunt durandal

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, durandal

I am having a go at grunt for optimizing my Durandal SPA. It seems to work great but now I would like to output a second file called libs.js which is the merged uglified version of all my required libraries but my first dist is getting ignored and still the only file I get is main-built.js

I only get one file so app/libs.js never gets created. I also have no grunt errors.

Here is my Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        durandal: {
            libs: {
                src: [
                    "../scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js",
                    "../scripts/typeahead.js",
                    "../scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js",
                    "../scripts/knockout-3.0.0rc.js",
                    "../scripts/toastr.js",
                    "../scripts/q.js",
                    "../scripts/breeze.min.js",
                    "../scripts/bootstrap.js",
                    "../scripts/moment.js",
                    "../scripts/lodash.js",
                    "../scripts/respond.js",
                    "../scripts/knockout-sortable.js",
                    "../scripts/knockout-bootstrap.js",
                    "../scripts/knockout.validation.js",
                ],
                dest: 'scripts/libs.js',
                options: {
                    uglify2: {
                        compress: {
                            global_defs: {
                                DEBUG: false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            dist: {
                src: [
                    "app/**/*.*",
                    "scripts/durandal/**/*.*"
                ],
                options: {
                    baseUrl: "app/",
                    mainPath: "app/main.js",
                    out: "app/main-built.js",

                    uglify2: {
                        compress: {
                            global_defs: {
                                DEBUG: false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadTasks('tasks');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['durandal']);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is JavaScript. If you create an object like `{ a: 'a', a: 'b' }`, the first key will be overwritten by the second by the VM.

Instead of configuring it like this:

```
dist: {
    // config goes here
},
dist: {
    // config goes here
}
```

Try

```
libs: {
    // config goes here
},
main: {
    // config goes here
}
```